# Identity of numpy.add

Tags: python, numpy, math, matrix

Consider 0+x =x where x is a number. 0 is called an identity of +.

Is there a identity of numpy.add?

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html

Comment: Doesn't 0 just work with arrays too?  Because of broadcasting.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sort of: `np.zeros_like()`. The identity is obviously the array of zeros, but you need the length of the arrays that you're adding to match up.

```py
>>> import numpy as np

>>> x = np.random.random(100)
>>> z = x + np.zeros_like(x)
>>> np.allclose(x, z)
True
```

Numpy functions that end in `_like()` are syntactic sugar for "the same shape as." So you can also use `np.zeros(x.shape)` to get the appropriate array of zeros. You can also just do `x + 0` and get the same effect, which begs the question of why knowing the identity would be useful.

Comment: you can just use `0`

Comment: Why eat up memory with an array-like of zeros when scalar 0 will broadcast anyway? I don't get it..

Comment: It is possible they want to start out with the identity and then modify it somehow?